# Android system calender

Tags: android, calendar, system

i want to delete calender event programatically.
i have tried below code:
int rows = getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), "calendar_id=? ",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(eventID)});

Answer (score 0):

Delete Events using this:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
Uri deleteUri = null;
deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(eventID));
int rows = getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
```

Here, rows gives you number of rows that affected by delete operation. use it to show if specific event is deleted or not.

Comment: to get the uri we need to get uri , this can be done using below uri shared in my post above:

Uri calendarURI = null;
try {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
calendarURI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
} else {
calendarURI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: i am using above code in my app and it is working perfectly. you just need an EVENTID to delete that.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below function:**

```
Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(getCalendarUriBase(), eventID);
getContentResolver().delete(eventUri, null, null);

private Uri  getCalendarUriBase() {
Uri calendarURI = null;
try {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
calendarURI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
} else {
calendarURI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return calendarURI;
}
```